# How does the "read" command work in Bash functions

Tags: bash

Just starting to use bash for the first time (so apologies if this is a dumb question).

As far as I've understood, `read` is used to receive user input. However, in the example below, it seems that it's also being used to assign function arguments.

Am I missing something here? Is there something else going on? I'm finding it hard to find documentation about how this works.

Any help would be appreciated

```
function server () {
  while true
  do
    read method path version
    if $method = 'GET'
    then
        echo 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
    else
        echo 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request'
    fi
  done
}
```

Comment: `read` is reading a line of input and *Word-Splitting* is applied to the line based on `IFS` (internal field separator, default `$' \t\n'`, `space`, `tab`, `newline`). The first whitespace separated word is assigned to `method`, the next to `path` and whatever is left over through end-of-line is assigned to `version`. See [man 1 bash](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) (search `"-ers"` to be taken directly to `read`)

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the `read` command is used to read input into 3 different variables `method`, `path` and `version`.

If the user enters as input the line `"my name is joe"`, then the values of `method`, `path` and `version` are:

```
method  -> "my"
path    -> "name"
version -> "is joe"
```

If, however, the user enters `"hello world"`, then only `method` and `path` will contain a string. Specifically:

```
method  -> "hello"
path    -> "world"
version ->
```

If you want to use the `read` command to read input into `N` variables, i.e. `read var1 var2 ... varN`, the user's input on the command line will be split/ delimited by the characters in the `IFS` variable. In fact, `IFS` stands for "Input Field Separators".

By default, the `IFS` variable is equivalent to `$' \t\n'`. This means that unless otherwise specified, user inputs are delimited by space, tab or the newline character.

EDIT: `IFS` is also commonly referred to as the "Internal Field Separator" as David pointed out in the comments (if you see this from other developers).

Comment: (quibble... it's "*Internal Field Separator*" `:)`

Comment: Ah that makes sense as well. When I learnt it I looked at this `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_Field_Separators`

Comment: Yes, that's why I always use the primary reference `man bash`, e.g. `"IFS    The Internal Field Separator that is used..."` I knew what you meant and it was apparent from context. Nicely written answer.